# How Prevent User for selecting start-date greater than end-date in `react-datePicker`?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-datepicker

How to Restrict in such that `startDate` should not be greater than `endDate` in react-datePicker

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date("2014/02/08"));
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date("2014/02/10"));
  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
        selectsStart
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
      />
      <DatePicker
        selected={endDate}
        onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        minDate={startDate}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[example demo react-datepicker docs](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `minDate` prop, you can use `maxDate` prop to set maximum selectable date in `DatePicker`

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
  selectsStart
  startDate={startDate}
  endDate={endDate}
  maxDate={endDate}
/>
```

Comment: Yes Thnks, found solution !!

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution :

**define `maxDate={endDate}` in start date picker**

```
 <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
        selectsStart
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
maxDate={endDate}
      />
      <DatePicker
        selected={endDate}
        onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        minDate={startDate}
      />
    </>
```